# Why would someone extend the Application class in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

Can anyone explain the need for `class A extends Application`. Why would we possibly do it in Android?

Comment: you mean application, not activity?

Comment: accessing singletons/complex objects from any place where you have a context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755900/how-careful-should-i-be-with-thread-safety-when-creating-methods-activities-which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application is things that will be global to the entire application regardless of current activity. The following tutorial is from an Android Bootcamp and its current focus is about the Application class. (It is a bit out of context without the rest of the series but it does demonstrate its use) http://www.youtube.com/user/MarakanaTechTV#p/c/E953C0B85B50AB62/8/jd_V7a6xhQc